# How to animate a rowView inside a ListView is a OnClickListener has been applyed to that view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I have a very complex listView in my application that can launch different activities based on some flags of each rowView (some rowView are even not enable to be clicked).

I choosed to add a OnClickListener on each of the rowView to launch the activities, but after I added the listener to the rowView, it no longer animates when I click on it (it should become darker, like the default android implementation).
RowViews without the listener still animates so I think I'm missing some calls to make it become darker.

Any hint?

EDIT: Since I got requested some code here's a simplified snap of my customAdapter's getView

```
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.customlistitem, null, true);

    if (infoList.get(position).isSeparator()){
        // Populate the view and don't add a listener
    } else {
        // Populate the view in some other way and add a listener
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, myActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("an_extra", new Object());
                intent.putExtra("another_extra", new Object());
                intent.putExtra("a_third_extra", new Object());
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    return rowView;
}
```

If the object has the flag isSeparator it become darker when I click it, otherwise it doesn't.

Comment: please post some code

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add a listener on each rowView. Set it on the ListView:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

Comment: I would avoid that solution cause the onItemClick would be very hard to mantain and read due to multiple flags to check. Since I already populate the ListView in different ways based on that flags i would like to add the listener inside the getView method to keep it readable and debuggable but still keep the animation effect of the standard ListView.

Comment: If you just need to view the pressed state effect use view.setSelected(true) inside onClick.